# Check solvability for the 8-puzzle problem without using O(n²) time

Tags: java

When checking whether the 8-puzzle assignment problem can be solved, we need to check invertability. The most intuitive way is to use a **double for loop** and iterate through the list. Is there a way of checking for invertability without being O(n²) time?

Answer (score 0):

For example you can try to use a quicksort algorithm, but every time you make a swap of two elements you increase an inversion counter. This way you'll get the number of inversions in O(n*log(n)) time.